# How to remove certain elements or elements with particluar class or ID in masonry?

Tags: jquery-masonry

Using this syntax to load Masonry items:

```
var msnry = new Masonry( "#container-div",
{
    columnWidth: 300,
    gutter: 10,
    isFitWidth: true,
    isAnimates: true,
    itemSelector: '.items',
    animationOptions:
    {
        duration: 600
    }
});
```

On click of a button or link I need to remove some items with `.sample` or `#sample` and this syntax does not works.

```
msnry.remove('.sample');
```

How to resolve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove masonry boxes with **particular selector** use this,

```
var remove=$('.sample'); // Use your removal class or ID here
msnry.remove(remove); // Attempting removal of the occurrences
msnry.reloadItems(); // Reload the layout
```